# What in-app purchase type to implement in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

My app is free for six month. after the end of sixth month,  I need to implement in-app to upgrade the app.
**Let imagine situation,after the end of sixth month if user not choose the inapp purchase and deleted  app. Now they install it again from appstore. so How can i find particular user installs my app again.**

I have read In-app store type. Its little confusing for me. I have implemented the Non-cpnsumable type so its basically purchasing a product for once and use it for long time. My case is also similiar but user should not use my app more than initial sixth months for free.

Comment: Regardless of your implementation this seems like a risky design given "11.9
Apps containing content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected, except for specific approved content (e.g. films, television programs, music, books)" https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use keychain to store the first time launch date. Every time app will lunch just check difference between stored date and current date. If 6 months over than allow user for purchase.
Keychain will not delete the data even the app is unInstall. It will keep the stored data after uninstalling the app also. Again if you will install and run the app it will give the old store data.

Comment: what will happen if user changes the date of the device?

Comment: Any date if you are taking this will depend upon device date only. If you want full control of date also then just take date from server. Tell server to give you the current date every time the app will run.

Comment: In that case devices with no connectivity will allow the app to run even after 6 months..

Comment: That also you can manage after storing both current device date and server date. If you are taking date from server then no point of without connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep on checking the current date from the app installation in the background process and validate your in-app purchase process when it reaches 6 months . I have attached a piece of code for your reference

```
-(void)dateCheck 

{

NSDate *current = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *weekFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[weekFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *expirDate=[current dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*14];

NSString *expireString = [weekFormatter stringFromDate:expirDate];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:expirDate forKeyPath:@"expireDate"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

}
```

Comment: If user will unInstall the app then NSUserDefaults value also get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use device UDID or device token for identification of device. And device with UDID will not allowed for more than six month. 
Also we can use account login for same. New login with new userid. And by considering both things , we can make identification.